# trying to pass an int variable from Activity to Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm trying to pass the int `pub_or_priv` from my `Activity1` to `Myadapter`.

I've looked at posts here and I think I've followed them correctly but it's still not working. The value in my `adapter` is always `0` whereas it should be `0`,`1` or `2`, as is the case with the value in my `Activity1`.

Here's what I've done.

In my `Activity1` I get `"publicorprivate"` from my server and convert it to an `int` with:

```
//convert public_or_private to an integer
pub_or_priv = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("publicorprivate"));
```

For different cells in my `recyclerView` it will be `0`,`1` or `2`.

Now I want to pass this to my `adapter` so in my `adapter` `contructor` I have:

```
public MyAdapter(List<Review> reviewUsers, Activity activity, int pub_or_priv) {

        this.activity = activity;
        the_reviews = reviewUsers;
        this.mPub_or_priv = pub_or_priv;

    }
```

And in my `Activity1`:

```
pAdapter = new MyAdapter(reviewList, this, pub_or_priv);
```

Then in `MyAdapter`:

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

            Review r = the_reviews.get(position);

            //shared_status will be Just U, Private or Public
            String shared_status ="";

            if(mPub_or_priv==0){
                //change colour depending on value
                ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DA850B"));
                shared_status = "Just U";
            }

            if(mPub_or_priv==1){
                ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0A7FDA"));
                shared_status = "Private";
            }

            if(mPub_or_priv==2){
                ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2AB40E"));
                shared_status = "Public";

            }


            ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setText(shared_status);

etc..etc..
```

However in the `recyclerView` in all cells the `phone_user_name` `textbox` is always `"Just U"`, in the `#DA850B` colour, whereas in fact it is supposed to be `Private` and `Public` in some cells, as per the `pub_or_priv` value in `Activity1`.

How can I get `pub_or_priv` correctly into my `adapter`?, thanks.

Comment: You'll need to add an int field in your `Review` class in order to keep track of the value for each item in the RecyclerView.

Comment: In my `Review` class I have a `getter` and `setter` for `publicorprivate` from server, like     `//get 0,1 or 2 value, for Just U, private or public
    public String getPublicorprivate() {
        return publicorprivate;
    }` and `public void setPublicorprivate(String publicorprivate) {
        this.publicorprivate = publicorprivate;
    }` I need to make another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using one value in the activity/adapter, so of course all rows show the same value.

In the adapter,  use the value in the Review instance that corresponds to the current cell:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    Review review = the_reviews.get(position);

    int pubOrPriv = review.getPublicOrPrivate();

    //shared_status will be Just U, Private or Public
    String shared_status = "";

    if (pubOrPriv == 0) {
        //change colour depending on value
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DA850B"));
        shared_status = "Just U";
    }

    if (pubOrPriv == 1) {
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0A7FDA"));
        shared_status = "Private";
    }

    if (pubOrPriv == 2) {
        ((ReviewHolder) viewHolder).phone_user_name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2AB40E"));
        shared_status = "Public";

    }

    //.............
}
```